# Connection to bitbucket using ssh keys can't be established

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

To be able to connect to my repositories in Bitbucket I did the following steps:

1. Executed (Windows 11 Powershell as admin): *ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -b 4096 -C "myemail@gmail.com"*. Public and private keys (*id_ed25519* and *id_ed25519.pub*) have been created in *C:\Users\myusername\.ssh*
2. In bitbucket I've added these keys: "My Repository" -> "Repository Settings" -> "SSH Keys"
3. I've started the ssh-agent: *Start-Service ssh-agent*
4. I've added the new ssh key to the ssh-agent: *ssh-add C:\Users\myusername\.ssh\id_ed25519*
5. I checked the key with: *ssh-add -l*. Looks good.
6. I tested the connection to bitbucket with: *ssh git@bitbucket.org*.

In the final step, I received the following error message: *git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).*

Is there anything missing or wrong in the steps above?

Comment: which key did you add to bitbucket? private or pub?
which key did you add to your local ssh-agent ?

Comment: Both keys. In Bitbucket you have to add both.

Comment: When adding the pub key I receive the message: It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the right way doing it, @clex. That's why you're receiving a message saying that your private key will be ignored

You should add only a public key to bitbucket and use a private key on your ssh-agent to authenticate.

Comment: I thought the same but Bitbucket doesn't let me add only the public key. It seems like adding a private key is mandatory on Bitbucket.

Comment: It's possible. 
I did add only the public key to my bitbucket account. The private key should not be shared with anyone. That's how the private-pub key pair works.

Comment: Maybe I have to add the public key on Bitbucket in "Repository Settings" -> "Access Keys" instead "Repository Settings" -> "SSH Keys"? In  "Repository Settings" -> "SSH Keys" it is mandatory also to add a private key.

Comment: I added the public to the ssh-key in the account-wide setting, not in any particular repository  https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/ssh-keys/

But it should work on each repository

Comment: Using your link I was able to find where to put in the pub keys. Thanks. I just can't find the page myself on Bitbucket. When I'm logged in I see an URL like this: https://bitbucket.org/myusername/workspace/overview. I can't the overall account settings, only repository settings or workspace settings.

Comment: Is account-wide ssh-key good enough for you or do you have to setup the key in a particular repo?

Comment: Account-wide ssh-key is good enough.